# Foursquare did not show any photos for venues at explore api

Tags: android, foursquare, android-location

I used Foursquare api for getting locations around user. When I view response of explore api at this link:

```
https://foursquare.com/developers/explore
```

that load some photos but when I call api from postman or in browser, photos array is empty for venue.
I set `venuePhotos=1` in my query but nothing show.
Please help me.
My query is like this:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore?near=rome&venuePhotos=1&query=launch&client_id=clientID&client_secret=clientSecret&limit=15&offset=0&v=20181224
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to upgrade your Foursquare Developer account from Sandbox to Personal. 
https://ja.foursquare.com/developers/verify